# Select an element that is in a class and append content after it

Tags: html, css

This is my specific example:

```css
input:invalid+span:after {
    content: 'wrong';
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #FF0000;
}

input:valid+span:after {
    content: 'correct';
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #00B300;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form method="POST" action="send.php">
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
            <span class="validity"></span>
            <br />
            <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't want to use first-child, last-child, etc because this CSS will be used amongst multiple HTML pages. The question is how I can use the class "validity" on my CSS to do the same thing as illustrated here, but only to spans that have the validity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class like `input:valid+span.validity:after` to change the content if it is valid.

I have also added the `div` as well as `span` without `validity` class to check your constrain

```css
input:invalid+span.validity:after {
  content: 'wrong';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #FF0000;
}

input:valid+span.validity:after {
  content: 'correct';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #00B300;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <form method="POST" action="send.php">
      <div>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```